# How to rename/change a custom post type slug/url?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, slug

I have a WP site with a custom post type called "lists", so when I do a post the url created is:

www.mysite.com/lists/mynewpost

I want to change it for:

www.mysite.com/classified/mynewpost

How can i do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For pepoles finding this question from Google. Solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52291839/4878858

Answer (score 0):

When you register your custom post type, you need to set the rewrite argument to something like `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'classified')`.

Take a look at the [post type documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#URLs_of_Namespaced_Custom_Post_Types_Identifiers). They cover it pretty well.

Comment: But i did not created this CPT, i'ts came with theme installation. Can i put this code into functions.php? how to do it?