# How to change slug in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type, slug

I have this URL for my *Resort* page `page-resorts.php`:

http://localhost/testwordpress/resorts/

After clicking the link to a post under *Resort* custom page I will have this URL for my custom page template (CPT) `single-resort.php`:

http://localhost/testwordpress/resort/kurumba-maldives/

As you can see the `resorts` was changed to `resort` because I can't use `resorts` slug for the slug post.

How can I achive this kind of URL:

http://localhost/testwordpress/resorts/kurumba-maldives/

where the `resorts` word is used and not `resort` word only?

I've heard about custom slug and search for it, but I still can't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your custom post type this way.

```
function create_posttype() {
  register_post_type( 'resort',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Resorts' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Resort' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resorts'),
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

**'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resorts'),** this used to add the slur on URL. this way you can acheive your URL.

Or you can override your current slug in **functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wpse247328_register_post_type_args', 10, 2 );
function wpse247328_register_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {

    if ( 'resort' === $post_type ) {
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'resorts';
    }

    return $args;
}
```

For more, please visit.

[register post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

[Change Custom Post Type slug](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247328/change-custom-post-type-slug)